# When retained property is released?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, properties

I have property like this:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *porpertyList;

@synthesize porpertyList = _porpertyList;

- (void)dealloc
{
[_porpertyList release];
}
```

And if i do this _porpertyList = @""; in my app. Property is released ?

//Edited
Now i don't understand when i should use this @synthesize porpertyList = _porpertyList; ?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, now replaced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use the `@property` option for variable name you should assign to it using the 
`self.propertyList = @""` rather then `_propertyList = @""`. using `self.propertyList` will release any previous memory it was using when u assign to it

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. But now i don't understand when i should use this  @synthesize porpertyList = _porpertyList;
?

Comment: have a read of http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/26587-slicks-definitive-guide-properties.html see if that clear is up for you

Comment: Wrong, gotta set self.property = nil, or it won't be very useful (@"" is NOT nil...)

Comment: i ment @"" as some kind of string that he was assigning it too. so self.propertyList = @"somestring"

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what memory model you are using. If you are using ARC, there's no need to write a dealloc to release retained properties, this is done for you. If you are not using ARC, you want to release the variables for the retained properties:

```
- (void) dealloc {
    [_propertyList release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Two things to note here:

1. You want to release the variable here, not set the property to nil. This avoids side-effects that could occur when using setters (custom behavior, kvo notifications).
2. Don't forget to call `[super dealloc];`

Comment: +1 for stressing release of instance variables (instead of setting properties to nil which could trigger kvo notifications).

Answer (score 2):

If you access property like this

```
self.property=@"";
```

you are in fact using setter method( which is auto-created thanks to @synthesize). So, in this case, the old object is released and new one is assigned and retained.

If you synthesized your property using

```
@synthesize property= _property;
```

then if you call

```
_property=@"";
```

then you just assign new value to the property. Nothing is being released then.

So, in your `dealloc` method you have some choices:

```
-(void)dealloc
{
   self.property=@"";//old value released, new value is @""
   self.property=nil;//old value released, new value is nil
   [_property release]; //old value released
   [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: The advice tends to be not to use setters (including implicitly via dot notation) in your dealloc because it is in effect calling methods on a part-deallocated object. One example of where this can blow up even if you've been careful in and of yourself is if someone subclasses your object and implements a more complicated setter — especially considering that your dealloc will occur after the subclasses has otherwise completely finished.

Answer (score 1):

```
@synthesize porpertyList = _porpertyList;
```

Whenever you synthesize an property... you up its retain count by 1..so that's why you have release in your dealloc.

```
Using self.propertyList = something
```

and

```
 porpertyList = something
```

are very different things and the latter one should be avoided when using properties..
**That is why porpertyList = _porpertyList;** is there..so that you don't use propertyList instead of self.porpertyList

The reason is ..**that popertyList is a pointer..**

when you do `self.porperty = something` ..you make a separate copy of that object for yourself(not in case of @"")
but if you do popertyList = something .. you make it point to another object thus messing with the whole retain count it had initially which can make your program behave strangely..

Answer (score 0):

`_porpertyList = @""` will not release anything. If you want to release, you can use `self. porpertyList = nil`. This will release it properly.